# How do I load binary files using Webpack's `raw-loader`?

Tags: webpack

Webpack's loaders usually load text files, so in most cases it's more convenient to have the contents of a loaded file converted using some text encoding (usually UTF-8). Binaries on the other hand, should not be converted, so there is a [`raw` property](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#raw-loader) for loaders, which controls (per loader) whether a UTF-8 conversion should be applied or not.

`raw-loader` is supposed to be loading raw data from files to strings without any conversion, so it might seem logical that it should be exporting the `raw` property as `true`. However, it doesn't and there is also a [unit test](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader/blob/5ec82d6c1fcfbbaebdb5b3d08cdad3719a5ffe2c/test/cjs.test.js#L9) which is supposed to ensure that `raw` is not exported. It seems it was designed to be used for text-based formats only.

Is there any way around this? What are the alternatives for loading binaries to strings?

Answer (score 7):

The `raw-loader` package seems to load properly only such text files that consist solely of 7-bit character codes 0-127, while it does not properly handle byte values >=128.

As resolution, use instead the `binary-loader` package that can load full 8-bit byte values into javascript string format. If necessary, you can then convert the string into Uint8Array.

Example:

```
// load contents of local file "test.bin" into a js string:
import binAsString from "!!binary-loader!./test.bin";

// if necessary, convert the imported string to Uint8Array:
let array = new Uint8Array(binAsString.length);
for (let i = 0; i < binAsString.length; i++) {
    array[i] = binAsString.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found a much cleaner solution. Use [Webpack's](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) `url-loader` and turn off the encoding in the options. You will also have to remove their default wrapper by modifying the `mimetype` and `generator` settings. Here is the working sample that I use in my `webpack.config.js`.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.bin$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
           options: {
             encoding: false,
             mimetype: false,
             generator: (content) => {
               return content;
             }
           },
         },
       ],
    }
  ],
},
```

This should import the file byte for byte. You can then grab the buffer and put it in a TypedArray constructor of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is thaw `raw-loader` is returning a string. Meaning that if you read a binary file and try to convert it to a string you might lose some bits.

The simplest way I found around this problem is to use the [binary-base64-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-base64-loader) which returns the content of the binary file in base64 format. A bit like the `url-loader` but without having to deal with the URL part.